# RenderWindow Constantly Updating display() Causing Flickering

Tags: c++, sfml, display

I am trying to write a program which allows users to draw using the mouse.  I have been trying many different ways to appropriately update the display using an object of `sf::RenderWindow` to call `display()` without much success.  My loop where the drawing is occurring is calling display so fast it's causing massive flickering (confirmed that through testing).  If I add a way to slow the call to `display()`, like using `sf::Clock`, then the drawing is only updated on the same delay as `display()` resulting in a stuttering effect.  What I need is a way to update the display often enough to show drawing updates while also not causing a screen flicker.

Currently, I've got the display on a delay (at the bottom of the event polling switch statement) so flickering doesn't occur, but adding `mainWindow.display();` to the `void MainWindow::draw()` function causes flickering as it updates too quickly.  I had the drawing occurring on `sf::Event::MouseMoved`, but I tried changing it to see if that would help, and it did not.

Here's where all the drawing and event detection occurs:

MainWindow.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GraphPaper.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class MainWindow
{
    public:
        MainWindow(short, short);
        void close();
        void start();
        void moveCamera(sf::Keyboard::Key);
        void draw(sf::Event);
        void displayWindow(sf::Vector2i&);

    private:
        bool leftMousePressed, rightMousePressed, isExiting;
        int r, g, b, mouseX, mouseY;
        short height, width;

        const short DRAWING_CRICLE_RADIUS = 10;

        GraphPaper paper;
        //DrawingBrush brush;

        const sf::Color WHITE = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);
        const sf::Color BLACK = sf::Color(0, 0, 0);

        sf::CircleShape circle;
        sf::Mouse cursor;
        sf::Vector2i windowCenter;
        sf::RenderWindow mainWindow;
        sf::View view;
};
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "GraphPaper.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(short height, short width)
{
    this->height = height;
    this->width = width;
    circle.setRadius(DRAWING_CRICLE_RADIUS);
    circle.setFillColor(BLACK);
}

void MainWindow::start()
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(height, width, 32), "Test");

    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0,0,height,width));
    mainWindow.setView(view);

    leftMousePressed, rightMousePressed, isExiting = false;

    sf::Event currentEvent;
    sf::Vector2i windowCenter(mainWindow.getPosition().x + (mainWindow.getSize().x / 2), mainWindow.getPosition().y + (mainWindow.getSize().y / 2));

    displayWindow(windowCenter);

    while (!isExiting)
    {
        sf::Clock clock;
        while (mainWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent))
        {
            switch (currentEvent.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
            {
                if (rightMousePressed == true)
                {
                    std::cout << "Mouse Panned\n";
                }
                if (leftMousePressed == true)
                {
                    draw(currentEvent);
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
            {
                std::cout << "Mouse Pressed\n";

                mouseX = currentEvent.mouseButton.x;
                mouseY = currentEvent.mouseButton.y;

                if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    while (currentEvent.type != sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Mouse is Drawing\n";
                        draw(currentEvent);
                        mainWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent);
                    }
                }
                else if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    rightMousePressed = true;
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
            {
                std::cout << "Mouse Released\n";
                if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    leftMousePressed = false;
                }
                else if(currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    rightMousePressed = false;
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            {
                sf::Keyboard::Key keyPressed = currentEvent.key.code;
                if(keyPressed == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                {
                    close();
                }
                else if(keyPressed == sf::Keyboard::Left || sf::Keyboard::Right ||
                                       sf::Keyboard::Down || sf::Keyboard::Up ||
                                       sf::Keyboard::A || sf::Keyboard::S ||
                                       sf::Keyboard::D || sf::Keyboard::W)
                {
                    moveCamera(keyPressed);
                    displayWindow(windowCenter);
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::Closed:
            {
                close();
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::Resized:
            {
                windowCenter = sf::Vector2i(mainWindow.getPosition().x + (mainWindow.getSize().x / 2), mainWindow.getPosition().y + (mainWindow.getSize().y / 2));
                displayWindow(windowCenter);
                break;
            }
            }
            if (clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= 500)
            {
                clock.restart();
                mainWindow.display();
            }
        }
    }
}
void MainWindow::moveCamera(sf::Keyboard::Key keyPressed)
{
    view = mainWindow.getView();
    switch (keyPressed)
    {
    case sf::Keyboard::A:
    case sf::Keyboard::Left:
    {
        view.move(-50, 0);
        break;
    }
    case sf::Keyboard::D:
    case sf::Keyboard::Right:
    {
        view.move(50, 0);
        break;
    }
    case sf::Keyboard::W:
    case sf::Keyboard::Up:
    {
        view.move(0, 50);
        break;
    }
    case sf::Keyboard::S:
    case sf::Keyboard::Down:
    {
        view.move(0, -50);
        break;
    }
    }
    mainWindow.setView(view);
}
void MainWindow::draw(sf::Event mouse)
{
    circle.setPosition(mainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(mouse.mouseMove.x, mouse.mouseMove.y)));
    mainWindow.draw(circle);
}
void MainWindow::close()
{
    std::cout << "Closing...\n";
    mainWindow.close();
    isExiting = true;
}
void MainWindow::displayWindow(sf::Vector2i& windowCenter)
{
    mainWindow.clear(WHITE);
    mainWindow.draw(paper.getSprite());
    mainWindow.display();
    cursor.setPosition(windowCenter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an important part of the rendering loop. You should draw all parts every loop iteration. Right now you are only drawing your circle when it's changed.

Your code should look like this:

1. change circle position based on input
2. clear window
3. draw circle
4. display

Comment: Well, I am only wanting to draw when the user is holding down the left mouse button. I'm not clearing the window because I am wanting to draw multiple circles to allow the user to make a shape like a painting program.  Regardless,  the window is still flickering because display is being called too often.

Comment: You need to clear, draw and display every loop iteration. If you want to keep what was drawn previously, remember the data (for example a vector of circles) and draw them every iteration.

Comment: @nviogt I'll be honest, I didn't expect that to work but it did.  Thanks.  Now I'm curious why simply not clearing the screen before displaying caused that.  I thought it was like an update function.  At any rate, I appreciate the help.

Comment: The theory is that you are supposed to draw the full scene every time. Nothing is remembered. If it seems as if something is remembered from the last drawing call, that's either a bug or a optimization feature you should not rely on.